# Add-Content : Access to the path 'C:\' is denied

Tags: powershell

Hello i have this problem

My problem:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> escribirInfo
Add-Content : Access to the path 'C:\' is denied.
At C:\Untitled2.ps1:41 char:72
+ ...  SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer | Add-Content C:\$nombre_fichero
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C::String) [Add-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand

```
main{
    crearFichero
    escribirInfo
}
function crearFichero
    {
    #Expliqueu que fa la funció!!!
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(

        )
        Begin
        {
        #RES
        }
        Process
        {
            $nombre_sistema = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name
            $ip = Test-Connection $nombre_sistema -Count 1 | select IPV4Address
            $ip_replace = $ip.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString.Replace(".","_")
            $fecha = Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy"
            $ext = ".txt"
            $nombre_fichero = [System.String]::Concat($ip_replace, $fecha, $ext)
            $crear_fichero= New-Item C:\$nombre_fichero -ItemType file
        }
    }

function escribirInfo
    {
    #Expliqueu que fa la funció!!!
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(

        )
        Begin
        {
        #RES
        }
        Process
        {
        gwmi win32_bios | select SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer | Add-Content C:\$nombre_fichero

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: [1] why all the powershell version tags? please, only use the one that fits your setup. [2] please show the code that triggered the error.

Comment: Okeey i have already done it

Comment: you have several problems in your code --- [1] the `main {}` structure is NOT used in powershell [2] your functions need to be defined BEFORE they are called. you have that reversed. [3] variables defined in a function are local to that function. your line 41 is attempting to write to C:\ - not to the file in the root ... to the root itself. WHY? because `$nombre_fichero` does not exist in the 2nd function - it was defined in the 1st function.

Comment: I'm a beginner i do not know hoy to do it

Comment: start with just one thing - one _very simple_ thing. make it work. add another thing. make them work with each other. don't use function util you have the items working with each other ... and even then, use functions only if they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Users have no permission to create files in the root of C:\ by default:

```
PS C:\> (get-acl c:\).Access


FileSystemRights  : AppendData
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : -536805376
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Alberto Martín Rodríguez,

@Gert-Jan-Kraaijeveld is right.  You can run as administrator or even better save files to somewhere in your user directory or another suitable location instead of the root of your primary drive.

i.e. C:\$nombre_fichero --> C:\Users{{YourUserName}}\$nombre_fichero